# How to re-write the query without using DISTINCT function in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-performance, query-performance

Without using DISTINCT function , how to achieve the same result.
TAB_C = 2947109424  rows, act = 43460 rows

```
    SELECT tc.email_addr_id 
                                 , COUNT(DISTINCT tc.m_act_id) AS num_12mons 
                                 , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD')  
                                     > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 90) 
                                     THEN tc.m_act_id ELSE NULL END) AS num_3mons 
                                  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD')  
                                      > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 180) 
                                      THEN tc.m_act_id ELSE NULL END) AS num_6mons 
                                  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD')  
                                      > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 270) 
                                      THEN tc.m_act_id ELSE NULL END) AS num_9mons 
                             FROM Tab_C tc     
                             INNER JOIN act a 
                             ON tc.act_id = a.act_id 
                             where a.channel_code IN ('FM','RM') 
                                 AND ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD') > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 365) 
                             GROUP BY tc.email_addr_id
```

Comment: DISTINCT - slows down the query in production

Comment: You have used ROUND by DD. If possible, use direct column there. Function on column will not allow use of index.

Comment: @Popeye , we have function based index on outbound_date, so if we use direct column (without round by dd) , is this not going to skip the functional index??

Comment: Ohh, If you have the function index then you should use ROUND to get benefit from index

Comment: @Popeye, thanks , but still no improvement , is there any alternative way we can re-design the DISTINCT CASE WHEN statement. Desperately looking for some input here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULLIF is supposed to be a lot quicker than CASE statements, and you might find that it's the CASE that's causing the slow rather than the distinct ... but it's all due to your indexing.  NULLIF obviously only works based on finding the correct value, rather than excluding the "wrong" values, so you have to reverse the search.

this *might* work better, but you'll need to double-check the results.

```
select email_addr_id,
    count(m_act_id) AS num_12mons,
    COUNT(nullif(sign(outbound_date +90 - ROUND(sysdate, 'DD')), -1))) AS num_3mons,
    COUNT(nullif(sign(outbound_date +180 - ROUND(sysdate, 'DD')), -1))) AS num_6mons,
    COUNT(nullif(sign(outbound_date +270 - ROUND(sysdate, 'DD')), -1))) AS num_9mons
from (
select distinct tc.email_addr_id, tc.m_act_id, round(tc.outbound_date, 'DD') as outbound_date
  from Tab_C tc     
  INNER JOIN act a ON tc.act_id = a.act_id 
  where a.channel_code IN ('FM','RM') 
    AND ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD') > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 365))
group by email_addr_id;
```

Comment: We have index in place on Tab_C.act_id  (join condition)

Comment: you could use additional indexes on act.channel_code since you filter by it, and you might want to create a function index for your "Round(tab_c.outbound_date)" : https://medium.com/@bbrumm/what-is-a-function-based-index-in-oracle-and-why-should-i-create-one-6e19e6912a55

Comment: created function index on Round(tab_c.outbound_date), but no improvement, will try on act.channel_code

Comment: JAD, i think column m_act_id is missing in num_3mons, num_6mons, num_9mons

Comment: no, he just wants a count, so I distinct the data first and null everything that doesn't match in order to get a count ... as I said this might well not work, he'd need to check the data output

Comment: ,its not just count , count of m_act_id , if it satisfies the 'case when' condition ...could you please re-modify it

Comment: how about that?

Comment: Thank you so much. Helpful.